# Adobe Animate gotoAndStop for Movie clip

Tags: html5-canvas, adobe

I created HTML5-canvas and added Rectangle like Movie (Movie1)
Then I created Animate for Movie1
But I don't know how works JS, when I try to stop Animate.

AS3 Action:Frame1

```
trace (this.Movie1);
this.Movie1.gotoAndStop(1);
```

How I need to write it on JS ?

I check different way but all of them doesn't work.

```
this.Movie1.gotoAndStop(1);
Movie1.gotoAndStop(1);
```

I opened console IE and saw

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'gotoAndStop' of undefined or null reference

also I wrote second Example

```
this.stop();
alert(this.Movie1);// output: MovieClip (name=null) 
//this.Movie1.gotoAndStop(1);

this.addEventListener('click', alertpopup);

function alertpopup(){

    //this.Movie1.gotoAndStop(1);
    alert(this.Movie1); // output:  undefined ???
}
```

So, I decided this task only when I inserted code in generated HTML file at the end Function Init(). Something like this

```
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;
function init() {
    // --- write your JS code here ---

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    exportRoot = new lib.ExAS3_Canvas();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);

    Update(exportRoot);
}

function Update(root){
  <!-- write your code here -->
  root.stop();
  //this.Movie1.name = 'Movie1';
  console.log("m=" + root.Movie1);
   root.Movie1.stop();

   root.Movie1.addEventListener('click', alertpopup);

   function alertpopup(){  
        root.Movie1.gotoAndStop(1);
        console.log("r=" + root.Movie1);
    }
}
```

Why the code is not working from the IDE ?

I try to change `this` on my first frame on `exportRoot` and it works partially

```
//this.Movie1.stop(); // it doesn't work 
//exportRoot.Movie1.stop(); // it doesn't work 
this.Movie1.addEventListener('click', alertpopup);
var i = 0;
function alertpopup(){
    i++;
    if(i==2) i = 0;
    exportRoot.Movie1.gotoAndStop(i);                       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that writing your code in the first frame gives a problem getting in touch with movieclips on the Stage (this.Movie1) - but putting the code in the second frame helps. Also I found, that the use of "this" inside a function sometimes gives the usual js-error: "this" refers to the function, and not to the object you are "inside" (Stage). Solve this problem by a variable "var that=this;" and use "that" instead of "this" inside the function.

Comment: Thank you for information. I think for  any program I need to use CreateJS  without IDE. It'll be more easily. But I don't have normal JS Editor for it instead of notepad++.